# Is there a method to finding if a file exist in a directory containing many subfolders?

Tags: c#, file, system.io.file

I am looking for an efficient way to search if a file exist in a given directory. 
The problem is I do not know the full path including all the subfolders. I only know the top level folder of the directory. 
Is there a way to search if a file exist in a entire directory without including the full path.

```
 //I would like to try this below
foreach(var file in files)
{
string filename = file.Name;
bool does_it_exist = File.Exists(C:\\,filename);
Console.WriteLine(does_it_exist);
}
```

Comment: What is the _files_ variable used in that loop? Is it a List or array of FileInfo instances?

Comment: You can use [Directory.GetFiles()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_). There's an overload that accepts a `searchOptions` parameter you can use to tell it to search subdirectories.

Comment: files is an array of FileInfo regarding another directory. I am checking if each file in the directory is also in another directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

string[] matchingFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles( path, "*ABC123*" );

Comment: That won't search subfolders.

Comment: Try this:

string[] matchingFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("c://", "ABC123", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

SearchOption.AllDirectories search in all subdirectories.